# how to flatten photo image which contains text only?

Tags: opencv

[image]

1. how can I detect the document has been folded (and possibly folded by none, once, or multiple times)
2. how can I correct section II so that it's turned into a rectangle?

Comment: what did you already try? do you want a completely automatic solution? Or is it feasible to click into the image and then do the correction?

Comment: Thanks for respond. I need a automatic solution.

I guess this can be achieved by:
1. we can assume the paper is alwasy white, and it's rectangle.
2. once it's folded, the number of vertice will change, thus we can probably know how many fold has been done
3. the vertices slit the pane into multiple ones, we can then use some transform to correct it.

sadly I'm not familiar with image processing.